# How to implode multiple arrays outside of foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, implode

I have a `foreach` loop and within the loop I am setting two of the rows as an array so that I am able to implode the array outside of the `foreach` loop. At first I just had the one array to implode, but now I need another.

I tried doing this, but it gave a an extra parameter error:
', $friends_pending_arr, $friends_pending_img_arr) .

How can I implode both `$friends_pending_arr` and `$friends_pending_img_arr` into the `pending_friend_user` class?

Variable I am wanting both implodes to take place.

```
$pending_friend_list = '<div class="pending-friend-list-row"><div class="pending_friend_user">'. implode
             ('</div><div class="pending_friend_list_decision"><div class="total-center">' . $pending_friend_list_approve . $pending_friend_list_decline . 
             '</div></div></div><div class="pending-friend-list-row"><div class="pending_friend_user">', $friends_pending_arr) .
             '</div><div class="pending_friend_list_decision"><div class="total-center">' . $pending_friend_list_approve . $pending_friend_list_decline . '</div></div></div>';
```

Full code:

```
$pending_friend_list = null;
    $pending_friend_images = null;
    foreach ($pending_friend_rows as $pending_friend_row) {
        $pending_friend_1           = $pending_friend_row['friend_one'];
        $pending_friend_2           = $pending_friend_row['friend_two'];
        $pending_friend_status      = $pending_friend_row['status'];
        $pending_friend_status_date = $pending_friend_row['date'];
        $pending_friend_img         = $pending_friend_row['img'];
        $total_pending_friends      = $pending_friend_1 . "<br>" . $pending_friend_2;

    if ($pending_friend_2 == $user_id) {
        $pending_friend_list_approve = '<img src="../icons/collection/checkmark.png" class="pending_approve_friend" alt="Approve Friend">';
        $pending_friend_list_decline = '<img src="../icons/collection/x-sign.png" class="pending_decline_friend" alt="Approve Friend">';
         $friends_pending_arr[] = $pending_friend_1;
         $friends_pending_img_arr[] = $pending_friend_img;
         $pending_friend_list = '<div class="pending-friend-list-row"><div class="pending_friend_user">'. implode
         ('</div><div class="pending_friend_list_decision"><div class="total-center">' . $pending_friend_list_approve . $pending_friend_list_decline . 
         '</div></div></div><div class="pending-friend-list-row"><div class="pending_friend_user">', $friends_pending_arr) .
         '</div><div class="pending_friend_list_decision"><div class="total-center">' . $pending_friend_list_approve . $pending_friend_list_decline . '</div></div></div>';
    }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're asking. Can you just use two `foreach` loops?

Comment: I need to take the variables `$pending_friend_img` and `$pending_friend_1` outside of the foreach loop, so I set each to an array. I then am calling `$pending_friend_1` outside of the loop by imploding the array I set it too. I am successfully doing this with `$friends_pending_arr` successfully, just cannot figure this out with the other variable as well.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong with this question?